# How should I structure my .plist array and dictionary?

Tags: iphone, ipad-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How should I structure my .plist array and dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7003748/how-should-i-structure-my-plist-array-and-dictionary)

I have UITableView that will have several child UITableViews which may also have 1 or 2 child UITableViews each.

What is the best way to structure this? This is what I have so far. I was able to load the initial parent table view with the data using

Code:

```
NSString* plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ICD9Disease" ofType:@"plist"];
NSArray *contentArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
```

But what do I have to do in didSelectRowAtIndex to make sure the next tableView loads up the correct data from the plist?

Comment: @jtbandes: The duplicate has exact same title. Great find.

Comment: wow thank you so much for your useful information..

Comment: @Praveen S: helps that I wrote an answer to the other one earlier today ;)

Comment: @Dylan: I'm pretty sure this is the same person who posted the other question (especially since the filename used is the same); I've flagged this post so the mods will probably take care of it shortly :)

Comment: thanks Dyan reich . i m new here so i not see the above question be possible duplicate

Comment: i just see that post , but not getting the answer as i need so i agin post sry i m new here so just trying to learn how to use stack overflow @dylan

Comment: @user887347 did you also ask the other question? If so, why are you making duplicate accounts?

Comment: @Tim Post: Looks like its the same user, jtbandes has also observed the same file name being used in the question.